# Get the integer value from an enum

Tags: enums, nim-lang

I am doing Advent of Code 2022 Day 2, and I have the following enums:

```
type
  GameMove {.pure.} = enum
    rock = 1, paper = 2, scissors = 3
```

and I'd like to be able to perform the following calculation:

```
ours = rock
theirs = scissors
echo ours - theirs
```

However, I get the error that there is no proc `-` defined for `<GameMove, GameMove>`. Indeed there isn't! But how can I define it, and/or how can I get the integer values from this enum in order to perform my calculation?

Answer (score 4):

[Converting to int](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74672678/2954547) does work, but apparently the correct answer (which is weirdly missing from [the language manual](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#types-enumeration-types)) is the [`ord`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#ord,T) function, in the `system` module:

```
ours = rock
theirs = scissors
echo ours.ord - theirs.ord
```

Edit: `ord` *is* mentioned in [the official tutorial](https://nim-lang.org/docs/tut1.html#advanced-types-enumerations), but only in passing, and it's easy to miss or forget!